# Обособление даты

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Блейн Самнер из города Оклахома-Сити государства США в течение двух лет, 1 апреля 2012 г. – 5 апреля 2014 г., оставался держателем абсолютного рекорда Мира, составлявшего тогда 400 кг.**

Верно ли, что я обособил запятыми дату в этом предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку это несогласованное формальное указание дат (две даты в именительном падеже через тире), его нужно было поместить в скобки. В варианте с запятыми для падежного согласования достаточно добавить предлоги: "с 1 апреля 2012 г. по 5 апреля 2014 г.", тогда это станет уточняющим оборотом.

Comment: То есть так? "Блейн Самнер из города Оклахома-Сити государства США в течение двух лет, с 1 апреля 2012 г. до 5 апреля 2014 г., оставался держателем абсолютного рекорда Мира, составлявшего тогда 400 кг."

Comment: @ArturBaibulatov - да, но при этом предложение все равно остается слегка нерусским

Comment: Я бы ещё США заключил в скобки, опустив слово "государства": Оклахома-Сити (США). Специально не проверял, но думаю, что "мира" нужно с маленькой.

Comment: Вы правы. Обычно "мир" пишут с маленькой буквы. Но я обычно пишу с большой и думаю, это допустимо.

Comment: Разве речь не о **мировом рекорде**? Зачем что-то придумывать взамен?